# Dynamically retrieve image dimensions using html/js

Tags: javascript, html, image, fabricjs

I am currently trying to create a web app to be able to upload images on a canvas using fabric.js. I am able to upload the images but have been unable to retrieve the dimensions of the image when I resize the image inside the canvas. Is there a way, that can be solved? Also, how do I handle it when multiple images are uploaded in realtime?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Project</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>


<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 0}).scale(0.2);
      console.log(oImg.height)
      console.log(oImg.width)
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 1});
      oImg.setControlsVisibility({ mtr: false })
      
     
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Fabric.js, an image's scaled width/height values can be obtained with the `getScaledWidth()` and `getScaledHeight()` methods.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Project</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>


<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 0}).scale(0.2);
      console.log(oImg.getScaledWidth())
      console.log(oImg.getScaledHeight())
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 1});
      oImg.setControlsVisibility({ mtr: false })
      
     
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I require to retrieve the current size of the image in the canvas in real time when it is being resized within the canvas itself and not the statically scaled dimensions of the image in the canvas

Comment: not sure what you mean by "statically scaled dimensions", but the `getScaledWidth`/`getScaledHeight` methods can be called at any time, including during scaling. Simply call them whenever you need the current image size.